# Need javascript confirm box dialogue & delete images when press ok

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

```
<?php
require "../db/dbconfig.php";
 $gal=mysql_query("select * from gallery");
 $numrows=mysql_num_rows($gal);
if($numrows>=1)
        {
echo "<form action='delete.php' method='post' name='f2' id='f2'>";
echo '<table id="rqst" style="display:block;" border="0" cellpadding="12" cellspacing="3" width="500px">';
    echo "<tr><th>Tick to select</th><th>Images in Gallery</th></tr>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($gal)
{
    $imgfile=$row['ImgName'];
$Image="<img src=gallery/".$imgfile." width='230px' height='150px'/>";

$img_name=$imgfile;



    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='imgs[]' value='$img_name'></td><td>".$Image."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";   
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td colspan='3' align='right'>";
   echo "<input type='submit' value='Delete' name='del'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

This is my code....This will display images from gallery and checkboxes associated with them. When I click delete button with unchecked checkboxes an alert should come like this "Please check at least one checkbox"..How to do that??

My next problem is,,when I click delete button after checked checkbox, alert should come like this=" Do you want to delete?? "...If clicked Ok,the image must be deleted else do nothing...Please help ...Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this below link for validation using jquery:

http://jsfiddle.net/susheel61/U3Unk/2/

```
<form id="form">
    First name: <input type="checkbox" name="firstname" class="check"><br>
    <button>test</button>
</form>


$("button").on("click",function(e){
    var status = $(".check").is(":checked");
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!status){
        alert("this is not checked");
    }
});
```

Comment: Dude it is displaying inside a loop so you cannot use id to validate checkbox. This id will be duplicate inside loop and it breach html properties.

Comment: just for example i have taken it. we can use 
    input[type=checkbox]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by javascript or jquery to validate whether your atleast one checkbox is select or not. So, for that you need to give a common class for all checkbox as example

```
<input type="checkbox" name="firstname" class="addchk">
```

Now in your submit button call a javascript function which validate the matter.

```
<input type='button' value='Delete' name='del' onclick='delete_checked()' />
```

Now write a function to validate whether any checkbox is selected.

```
function delete_checked()
{

     var status = $(".addchk").is(":checked");
     e.preventDefault();
    if(!status){
           alert("this is not checked");
     }
     else
     {
          // SUbmit yout form
     }
}
```

Comment: <form>
<input type="checkbox" name="firstname" class="addchk"><br>
      <input type='button' value='Delete' name='del' onclick='delete_checked()' />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function delete_checked()
{
alert("hi");
     var status = $(".addchk").is(":checked");
     e.preventDefault();
    if(!status){
           alert("this is not checked");
     }
     else
     {
          // SUbmit yout form
     }
}
</script>

alert "Hi" displays...but i dint get checkbox validation...

Comment: when i run this,i'm getting an error "object expected" in error console...in line  var status = $(".addchk").is(":checked");